# What is the demonym for those who are born and bred in the district of Bragança, in the extreme Portuguese northeast?

Tags: gentílicos

There is a city in São Paulo, Brazil, called "Bragança Paulista".  Those who are born there are called "bragantinos".  What is the demonym for the Portuguese district of Bragança?  I've heard "brigantino", "bragançano", and "braganção".  Perhaps those from southern Portugal use one form and those from the north use another. I'm interested in learning which one a native from Bragança would choose to refer to himself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My source, a friend born and bred in the [town of Bragança](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragan%C3%A7a,_Portugal), tells me people from her home town are ***brigantinos*** or ***bragançanos***. *Brigantino* is the more common demonym, and derives from the town's ancient name [Brigantia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigantia_(goddess)#Evidence_for_Brigantia). I am not aware of a name for people from the [distrit of Bragança](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragan%C3%A7a_District) as such, or for people from any other Portuguese district for that matter.

People in Portugal identify themselves with their municipality, which, unlike districts, are very old entities with directly elected officials. The distric of Bragança comprises twelve municipalities. There are names for people from each of these: ***mirandês*** or ***mirandense*** for someone from [Miranda do Douro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_do_Douro), ***vila-florense*** for  someone from [Vila Flor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vila_Flor), and so on.

Comment: It could be interesting to note that people in Portugal also identify themselves with their region, although not as often as with their municipality - transmontano, algarvio, and so on.

Comment: True, a bragantino would accept to be called transmontano, but that's somewhat outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Jacinto, I really can't understand how the people of a certain town can use two different demonyms to refer to themselves.  Do you know which one prevails ?

Comment: I've relayed the question.

Comment: @Centaurus: My friend tells me *brigantino* is the more common demonym. Incorporated it in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Portugal, those from Bragança are *brigantinos* or *bragantinos*.

[Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragan%C3%A7a_%28Portugal%29) also registers *bragançano*, *braganção*, and *bragancês*, but as a *portuense* I'm not familiar with these.

It's difficult to be sure; because of the complexity of the demonyms (*albicastrense*, *escalabitano*, *oliventino*, etc), they are often not very well-known. This could easily explain the origin of the different registers.

Further reading: [WP>lista de gentílicos de Portugal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_gent%C3%ADlicos_de_Portugal)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is not what they are called in Portugal, but what they are called in Bragança.

Comment: You forgot to downvote, @Centaurus . :) (`This answer is not useful`, says the downvote tooltip.) I did not notice the stress on "what *they* call themselves" when I read the question; maybe you could rephrase it.

Comment: ANeves, I didn't forget.  Instead, I'm upvoting it.  It may not be the right answer but +1 for trying.

Comment: Good link.  A complete list of demonyms.